# SpringMVC can not bind json correctly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

There a json object to be sent to the server, which contains a field：

```
{"sName":"something"}
```

In my request model,I declare a var with the same name:

```
String sName;
```

But I got null when I receive in the Controller.

I change the field name to lower-case(`sname`) or add `JsonProperty(value="sName"`) annotation,it work. So where is the problem？

Controller

```
public ResponseEntity<JSONObject> getComprehensiveInquiryCp(@Validated @RequestBody ComprehensiveInquiryRequestModel body) {
        Map<String, Object> content;
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
        String sLicense = body.getSLicense();
...
}
```

ComprehensiveInquiryRequestModel

```
@Data
public class ComprehensiveInquiryRequestModel {
...
    //@JsonProperty(value = "sLicense")
    private String sLicense;
...
}
```

Comment: first your json object is wrong, it should be {"sName":"something'"}

Comment: can you add full code

Comment: @Hemant updated.

Answer (score 1):

From top of my head: if you have accessors in that bean, then I think jackson prefers to use them if they exist.  And/or Jackson prefers accessors for private fields. As you noticed you can alter that behaviour with Jakson configuration (for example via annotions).

Try: 
 1. to debug, remove accessor methods and make field public. If that works then change the field back to private and make sure accessor methods are named correctly.

Also single charater prefixes are not a good practise. They can be problematic and confusing. Prefixes in general are lazy and un-Clean Code(tm) practise.

Answer (score 0):

It is important that your setters (and getters) are present and actually conform to the Java naming conventions. A json property named "myFirstName" usually requires a public setter "setMyFirstName(...)" for example. So "sName" needs "setSName()", I guess.
Sure sounds like the naming convnetion might be at fault here.